# Can anyone tell me why is this loop run forever?

Tags: javascript, loops

```
let dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
while (dice !== 6) {
    console.log(You rolled a ${dice}); 
}
```

Please explain this code?

Comment: The value of `dice` is set only once, before the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to assign `dice` value in `while` loop until `dice !== 6`

```js
let dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
while (dice !== 6) {
  console.log(`You rolled a ${dice}`);
  dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, and only once, you generate a random number (`dice`).

If that number is a 6 it skips over the while loop.

If it isn't a 6 it enters the while loop.

The value of `dice` **doesn't change inside** the while loop, so it goes round and round forever.

Answer (score 0):

you have never selected the next random dice. include the dice statement in you loop so you have a new value for dice variable else it will always have same value.

Answer (score 0):

You set the value of dice only once at the beginning, if you get a different number than 6 then the loup will iterate forever, try to put

> Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1

as a condition for the while loop, then you will get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

The value of `dice` is set only once, before the loop. A variable retains its value unless you explicitly change it.

What you could do is create a small *function* to use for a dice roll. It saves you from having to type out the code in the function more than once:

```
let dice = () => {return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;}

roll = dice(); /* Set the initial value of roll */
while (roll !== 6) {
    console.log(`You rolled a ${roll}`);
    roll = dice(); /* Set the value for the next time round in the loop */
}
```

Notice that the call to the function has parentheses `()` to make it evaluate the function.